# EventMachine send data to one client (From Multi Server )

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I have developed multiple eventmachine servers which are like

```
require 'eventmachine'

module EchoServer
 def post_init
  puts "-- someone connected to the echo server!"
 end
 def receive_data data
   send_data ">>>you sent: #{data}"
  close_connection if data =~ /quit/i
 end
 def unbind
  puts "-- someone disconnected from the echo server!"
 end
end

EventMachine::run {
EventMachine::start_server "127.0.0.1", 8081, EchoServer
EventMachine::start_server "127.0.0.1", 8082, EchoServer
EventMachine::start_server "127.0.0.1", 8083, EchoServer
}
```

Now I need to send data to the client as per the port only 8082. If I have all the connections open . Server needs to send back data to the perticular server. 
So If From 8081 I get the request  I need to send it to 8082 client.
How do I send that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the modification of the original question, I posted a new answer.

You will need to track the server `port` for each connection. And when a new connection is established from port 8082, store that connection until it is closed. And when you get data from clients connected by 8081 port, send data to all connections stored before.

```rb
require 'eventmachine'

$clients = []

module EchoServer
  def initialize(port)
    @port = port
  end

  def post_init
    puts "-- someone connected to the echo server!"
    $clients << self if @port == 8082
  end

  def receive_data data
    send_data ">>>you sent: #{data}"
    # data is from a client connected by 8081 port
    if @port == 8081
      $clients.each do |c|
        c.send_data ">>>server send: #{data}"
      end
    end
    close_connection if data =~ /quit/i
  end

  def unbind
    puts "-- someone disconnected from the echo server!"
    $clients.delete self if @port == 8082
  end
end

# Note that this will block current thread.
EventMachine.run {
  # arguments after handler will be passed to initialize method
  EventMachine.start_server "127.0.0.1", 8081, EchoServer, 8081
  EventMachine.start_server "127.0.0.1", 8082, EchoServer, 8082
  EventMachine.start_server "127.0.0.1", 8083, EchoServer, 8083
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `telnet 127.0.0.1 8082` under you console/shell.

```
-> ~ $ telnet 127.0.0.1 8082
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
hello
>>>you sent: hello
quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

If you want to send data from Ruby code, take a look at [`socket`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html) library.

```rb
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new '127.0.0.1', 8082

s.puts "Hello"
puts s.gets     #=> >>>you sent: Hello

s.close
```

Comment: I have updated the question.From 8081 I get the request I need to send it to 8082 client. How do I send that?

Comment: @hbdevror when you decide to send data to client connected to 8082 port, there might be thousands of clients active, which one would you like? Or you want to send to all of them? It's strange requirement.

Comment: All those clients which are connected with 8082. Means To the particular clients from server